# How to explicitly set "justify" for paragraph?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, xetex, paragraphs, text-decorations

Is there a way to explicitly set "justify" for paragraph in latex or xelatex?
(some tricks or packages??)

Comment: What does it mean to "set justify"? Can you make the question more clear about what exactly you want?

Comment: like align="justify" in HTML

Comment: What about ragged2e? But justification is default...

Comment: Instead of explicitely re-justify the text, you should limit the scope using a `center` or `flushleft`  environment.

Comment: if it (ragged2e) can justify paragraphs -- maybe you can make an answer??

Comment: I want a way to set justifying explicitly -- sometimes it is conviniet

Comment: brute force: `\rightskip=0pt \par`.  but the suggestions given in other comments are better.

Comment: how did you specify that it be non-justified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I think it's a duplicate here's an answer: To explicitly force justification you can use `ragged2e`. It provides `\justifying` for that. From the documentation:

> `\justifying` switches back to justified text after ragged text has been.